# strace all but specified system calls

Tags: system-calls, strace

How can I run `strace`, and record all of syscall , but not `read` and not `write`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
strace -e '!read,write' your-command and args
```

If you want to learn more about a command, best it to read its documentation. The `strace` documentation is available in `man` format, so it's just a matter of running `man strace`. In there, you'll find a section about *Filtering* which describes the syntax of `-e` operands.